# How to Create Multi-Valued List in Team Foundation Server/Microsoft Test Manager?

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I am working on VSTS 2010 and using Microsoft Test Manager to manage our team's test cases. I just want to add a custom field for Test Categories (with values like BVT, FVT, Regression etc..) to the existing Test case template by following the steps [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=755) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2011/09/21/customize-your-test-case-work-item-template-to-enable-query-on-test-suites-test-plans-test-categories-and-execution-statistics.aspx). But I am not able to select multiple values. I am able to create a drop down list with one of these values can be selected but not more than one. but since a test case can be part of more than one test category, how can I make this possible?

My steps:

1. In Process Editor, Work item types I Create a new field called Test Category with Ref Name as MyCustomField
2. In Rules, I selected AllowedValues as BVT, FVT, Regression.
3. After that, In Layout tab created a new control with name Test Categories
   4.The field name of the control is set to MyCustomField
4. When I checked in MTM to create a new test case, the control is showing as drop down instead of one that was shown [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2011/09/21/customize-your-test-case-work-item-template-to-enable-query-on-test-suites-test-plans-test-categories-and-execution-statistics.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control you are trying to use is strictly 1 to 1 (does not allow for multiple values), so there isn't really a simple answer to this question, but here are some options:

1- Create 3 custom fields BVT, FVT, and Regression each with a yes/no input.

2- Follow the steps here: [Multi-value list control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/02/15/multivaluelist-control-in-tfs-work-item-tracking.aspx)

3- Upgrade to VS2012 and use tagging.